# Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script to list all groups in the active directory that are created in the last 21 days. This works fine but sometimes a group can be managed by a user or by another security group. And I would like it to display the 'Display name' of the user/security group.

What I have created so far:

```
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-21)).Date

Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=Groups,OU=BEL,OU=EU,DC=domain,DC=net" -Filter     {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties * |
Select whenCreated, cn, displayName,GroupScope, GroupCategory, description, info,@{Label='managedBy';Expression={
if(Get-ADObject $_.managedBy -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "user"')
{(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties displayName).displayName}
Else{(Get-ADGroup $_.managedBy -Properties cn).cn}
 }

| Export-Csv "New groups -21 days.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding utf8; start "New groups -21 days.csv"
```

It says: Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal and I can't seem to figure out what needs to be changed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing underscores from your variables **$.managedBy** and **$.Manager**. Both should be  `$_.managedBy`  `$_.Manager` and a closing brace is missing.

```
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-21))
Get-ADGroup -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties * | 
Select whenCreated, cn, displayName, GroupScope, GroupCategory, description, info, 
@{
    Label='managedBy';
    Expression={
        if(Get-ADObject $_.managedBy -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "user"') {
            (Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties displayName).displayName} 
        Else{
            (Get-ADGroup $_.managedBy -Properties cn).cn
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv "New groups -21 days.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding utf8; start "New groups -21 days.csv"
```

Comment: The missing underscores are only a formatting problem.. If you try to edit the OP youl'll see.

Comment: I'll mark this a answer, because it fixed the syntax problem. I'll open a new question to check for the logic behind it as it's not working properly. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Check your syntax on that calculated property.  Your braces are out of balance (there should be another } at the end to close the hash expression).